# React property not appearing as query parameter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a small form which I am using to pass a value in through URL (as a query parameter). The form is given below:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" value={`${this.props.age}`} name="p" />
    <a href="profile" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">View</a>   
</form>
```

The idea is to access the age value from the URL in the new page. Something like:

```
http://localhost:8000/?age=13
```

However, when I am clicking the link, no query parameter appears in the URL. Does someone know how this can be fixed? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `<button>` instead of `<a>`., because when you click on `View` you go to `/profile/` page (`href` has property `/profile/`) but not submit form to server. `type` attribute for `button` and `a` have different meaning

> **button** - The [`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) attribute specifies the type of button.
>
> **a** - The [`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_type.asp) attribute specifies the Internet media type (formerly known as MIME type) of the linked document.

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" value={`${this.props.age}`} name="p" />
  <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">View</button>
</form>
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/45407/)

---

also you can trigger [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method, and prevent default action for `<a>`

```
var App = React.createClass({
  submit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.refs.form.submit();
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return <form method="GET" ref="form">
      <input type="hidden" value={`${this.props.age}`} name="p" />
      <a href="profile" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={ this.submit }>View</a>   
    </form>;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/45406/)

Answer (score 1):

An `<a>` tag doesn't submit your form, only redirects to a different url.

The following should work:

```
<form method="GET" action="profile">
    <input type="hidden" value={this.props.age} name="p" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">View</button>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` tag only redirect to a page.
Then you may want to add some css code to make the button look like an `<a>` tag.

```
<form method="GET" action="profile">
<input type="hidden" value={this.props.age} name="p" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">View</button>   
</form>
```